# Recursivity in adjacent matrix R

Tags: r, algorithm, matrix

I'm trying to create a function that finds all possible pathways (I'll call them from now on subpathws) in groups of three at maximum (father node + two son nodes). That means if there is a pathway such `A,B,C,D`  I should be getting as subpathways `A,B,C` `B,C,D` `C,D` and `D`, but I believe that Ideally I would like not to have the last two because those are already represented in the previous subpathways. I want to have all subpatways to be contained in a list `subpaths`.

I created a toy adjacent matrix,filled with 0 and 1, where o means no connection between nodes and 1 means connection. Being the row name the father node and the column name the son node.

```
nombre <- c("A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F")
Mprueba <- matrix(c(0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0), ncol = 6)
colnames(Mprueba) <- nombre
row.names(Mprueba) <- nombre
```

This is the closest function that I made to work properly, it seems to travel all nodes and as I have tested putting some prints within the function it seems to be doing it as expected. This is just a scaffold I have not placed any return in the code below because none of them were working as expected.

```
subpaths_3_nodes <- function(matriz, i = 1, subpaths , subpath3){

  subpath3 <- c(subpath3, row.names(matriz)[i])


  if (sum(as.numeric(matriz[i,])) == 0){

    subpaths <- c(subpaths, list(subpath3))
    subpath3 <- c()
  }

  if (length(subpath3) >= 3){

    subpaths <- c(subpaths, list(subpath3))
    subpath3 <- c()


  for (edge in which(as.numeric(matriz[i,]) == 1)){
    subpaths_3_nodes(matriz, edge, subpaths, subpath3)
  }

  }

}
```

Then I run the function by putting it in a loop that travels across all rows of the matrix. I have also created the function with the loop inside of it, but I have not being able to make it work properly.

```
subpath3 = c()
subpaths = list()
for (i in 1:dim(matriz)[1]){subpaths_3_nodes(matriz,i, subpaths, subpath3)}
```

The code I have put above is just a scaffold (it probably lacks of some `return` functions )as I have created several versions of it and none are giving me the expected output, I hope it helps.

Thanks for your time and sorry for this messy post.

Comment: Could you also add your expected outcome please. .

Comment: I would expect for this example this (maybe in this case from BCE to the end I would not need it):
ACD
ACE
AF
BCD
BCE
CD
CE
D
E
F

Comment: I would use `igraph` package for this: `g <- graph_from_adjacency_matrix(Mprueba) ; lst <- lapply(V(g)$name, function(x) all_simple_paths(g, from=x, mode="out"))` gets you fairly close. To select three edge paths : `setNames(lapply(lst, function(x) x[lengths(x)==3]), V(g)$name)` [also you can use `shortest_paths`, which may be more efficient, and you may also find `ego` function useful

Comment: Thanks. I'll give it a shot and if it works I'll use it, but I was hoping being able to create properly a function for it, but seems more complicated that I thought.

Comment: Doing this sort of search is non trivial, and (imo) its best to stick with specific graph algorithms